# Trying the REST API with Insomnia REST Client (Session expire or invalid session)

Tags: rest-api

GOAL: Use Insomnia REST Client to get data from Salesforce (REST API), in order to implement a server to server solution where I get data (programmatically) from Salesforce without interactively login.

What I have done:

- configure an App in Salesforce to get a `client_id` and `client_secret`
- Reset security token to use with the username password. `password` = `PASSWORD` + `SECURITY TOKEN`, see below

[image]

I am able to get an `access_token` with `200 OK`

[image]

Then I use the `access_token` above to get data by setting `Authorization` bearer as a header. It fails with `Session expired or invalid` `401 Unauthorized`

Any pointers on what I am doing wrong? or on how to use Insomnia REST client?

[image]

Comment: Try disabling "Lock sessions to the IP address from which they originated" per this article - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000335524&type=1

Comment: Also, as a side note, the Username-Password flow is not recommended for anything but testing. The JWT Bearer flow is the suggested one for non-interactive (server-server) authentication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure to use the same domain as that is returned in your instance url (my.salesforce.com is what I see from your screenshot) field when you obtained the token.

If you try to use lightning domain it will be unauthorized request.

Comment: Following your pointers, I was able to resolve my issue. See what resolved my issue in my Answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The URLs I was using were not correct.

On step 1, to get the token, I used `https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token` instead of `p****v.lightning.force.com/services/oauth2/token`.

That wasn't the issue, and I get a proper `access_token` too

[image]

On step 2, to fetch data, I used `https://p*****v.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v52.0`.
It is `.my.salesforce.com` instead of `.lightning.force.com`.
That was my issue.

[image]